# Why does my object disappear in camera view?

Tags: clipping

My object disappears when I go into camera view. I tried increasing the clipping end in the view menu in the viewport, but that does nothing. I tried increasing the clipping end in the camera settings, but that didn't do anything either.

[video](https://imgur.com/a/LGWHxD5)

Comment: pls provide blend file - thx

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QVs7FZUeap2FoyT9PEaLlCOltBu4no5S/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your material you need to disable the *Show Backface* option or make it *Opaque* otherwise you'll have these glitches, Eevee doesn't manage transparency behind transparency very well.

Comment: yes. that worked! thank you